# Кол-во соединений в AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Вообщем есть такая проблема, я в своем виджете отправляю файлы через ajax вот так:

```
$('.copy_to_disk').on('click', function () {
    var a    = $(this).parent('div').find('a');
    var href = a.attr('href');
    var name = a.attr('data-name');

    $(this).parent('div').find('span').css('top', '-36px');
    $(this).remove();

    // TODO: Прелоадер, появляется при загрузке файла на yadisk
    var base_image = 'https://site/img/widgets/yadisk/preloader.gif';

    var ids = Date.now();
    var html = $('' +
    '<div class="load_file_in_progress" id="' + ids + '" style="width:100px;display:inline-block;margin:10px 30px;vertical-align:top;">' +
                    '    <img src="'+ base_image +'" width="100" height="75" style="border:1px solid #dbdedf;padding:10px;"/>' +
    '</div>');
    $('#yandex_files').append(html);

    var data_to_copy = '';
    if (self.essence == 'check_contact') {
        data_to_copy = 'amo_domain=' + self.domain + '&amo_user_id=' + AMOCRM.constant('user').id + '&contact_id=' + self.contactId +
                        '&lead_id=' + self.leadId + '&lead_name=' + self.leadName + '&contact_name=' + self.contactName +
                        '&filename=' + name + '&file_url=' + href + '&rootFolder_amo=' + self.essence + '&ids_to_file=' + ids;
    } else {
        data_to_copy = 'amo_domain=' + self.domain + '&amo_user_id=' + AMOCRM.constant('user').id + '&company_id=' + self.companyId +
                        '&lead_id=' + self.leadId + '&lead_name=' + self.leadName + '&company_name=' + self.companyName +
                        '&filename=' + name + '&file_url=' + href + '&rootFolder_amo=' + self.essence + '&ids_to_file=' + ids;
    }

    self.sendAjax(self.baseUrl + self.url.copyFile, 'POST', data_to_copy, true, self.callbackCopyFiles);
});
```

Вообщем таким образом я могу отправить хоть 10 файлов проблема в том, что иногда id не ставится в заглушку. Мне надо как-то определить кол-во действующих соединений через AJAX, но как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете [использовать](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L282) `$.active` для просмотра количества активных соединений. Обратите внимание что минимальная, в которой доступно это поле, версия jQuery 1.4.2.

Если ваша версия jQuery ниже вы можете [использовать](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) `ajaxStart` и `ajaxStop` для подсчета.

```
var count = 0;
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function() {
    count++;
  })
  .ajaxStop(function() {
    count--;
  });
```

Comment: Я бы сказал, что это костыль, но вполне подойдёт

Comment: Если у вас есть другая идея как это можно сделать,  мы можем её обсудить в чате.